# How to set JAAS serviceName when using com.ibm.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule

Tags: apache-kafka, kerberos, jaas, websphere-liberty

I have a Kafka producer web application hosted on IBM Websphere Liberty Core. The remote Kafka topic is secured via Kerberos.

We are using the IBM jdk so the jaas classname is

```
com.ibm.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule
```

The JAAS config requires the following options

```
KafkaClient {
     com.ibm.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
     useKeyTab=true
     keyTab="/etc/security/keytabs/storm.service.keytab"
     storeKey=true
     useTicketCache=false
     serviceName="kafka"
     principal="storm@EXAMPLE.COM";
    };
```

Unfortunately the `com.ibm.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule` class only accepts these options

```
 Kerberos options
       principal=principalName
       credsType=initiator|acceptor|both (default=initiator)
       forwardable=true|false (default=false)
       proxiable=true|false (default=false)
       renewable=true|false (default=false)
       useCcache=URL
       useKeytab=URL
       useDefaultCcache=true|false (default=false)
       useDefaultKeytab=true|false (default=false)



 JAAS-suggested options:
       debug=true|false (default=unset, JGSS debug options used)
       tryFirstPass=true|false (default=false)
       useFirstPass=true|false (default=false)
       moduleBanner=true|false (default=false)
```

How do you specify serviceName as 'kafka' with IBM JDK on Liberty Core?

Comment: The funny thing is that I could not find any reference of that `serviceName` property in the Sun/Oracle Java documentation. And The HortonWorks documentation for Kafka mentions that *"serviceName="kafka" is required for connections from other brokers"* so I would assume that this is a **custom** parameter, not used by JAAS itself.

Comment: Bottom line: just take care of the documented parameters (i.e. `keyTab` fusioned with `useKeytab`, `useTicketCache` renamed `useDefaultCcache`, implicit `storeKey` based on using cache or not), leave the custom `serviceName` that is used by the Kafka client only, and give it a try. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The Kerberos service principal name includes the service name:

```
<serviceName>/<hostname>@KerberosRealmName
```

Have you try to specify it as the following

```
principal="kafka/<hostname>@EXAMPLE.COM"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Oracle JDK Krb5LoginModule configuration. I can't find any Oracle document for the serviceName:

```
    KafkaClient {
        com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
        useKeyTab=true
        keyTab="/etc/security/keytabs/storm.service.keytab"
        storeKey=true
        useTicketCache=false
        principal="storm@EXAMPLE.COM";
    };
```

Here is the equivalent of IBM JDK Krb5LoginModule configuration:

```
    KafkaClient {
        com.ibm.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
        useKeyTab="/etc/security/keytabs/storm.service.keytab"
        useDefaultCcache=false
        principal="storm@EXAMPLE.COM";
    };
```

If this is a client configuration side where the client need to get the Kerberos or SPNEGO token to go outbound, then principal="storm@EXAMPLE.COM"

If you already has Kerberos configuration that worked with Oracle JDK and want to migrate to IBM JDK, please share the configuration and I will provide you with an equivalent configuration for IBM JDK.

Regards,

Ut Le